# Significato di "attassare"

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Rocchino si sentí le braccia e le gambe che si **attassavano**. Per forza, adesso era chiaro: di fronte a lui c'erano le anime dei dannati, che ogni tanto scappano dall'inferno e si riuniscono sulla terra per portarsi dietro qualche cristiano battezzato. Li riconosceva dalle guance scavate e dagli occhi febbrili. [...] 
>         Ma oltre alla paura che gli legava le gambe, c'era qualcos'altro che tratteneva Rocchino.

Non ho trovato questo verbo, "attassare", su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Comment: Che forse derivi da *atassia*? Infatti con il termine *atassia* si suole indicare la mancaza di coordinazione dei movimenti muscolari volontari sicché *attassare* avrebbe il significato di muoversi in maniera scordinata, proprio come se si fosse indemoniati! Tuttavia credo la mia non sia la migliore delle spiegazioni: infatti credo che la "verbizzazione" del termine *atassia* sia *atassare* e non *attassare*. Probabilmente si tratterà di qualche italianizzazione di un verbo dialettale.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro:  Non credo che Rocchino si movesse in questo modo. Era estremamente impaurito perché aveva visto queste persone, in realtà briganti, che lui pensava fossero anime scappate dall'inferno.

Comment: Può darsi che Rocchino tremasse (il tremolio è una reazione involontaria) cosicché i suoi muscoli compievano spasmi involontari?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: Ho aggiunto una frase che appare più avanti nel testo per dare un po' più di contesto.

Comment: Allora probabilmente si tratta di una qualche italianizzazione di un verbo dialettale.

Comment: Cercando su Google sembra che *attassare* sia un verbo del Siciliano che avrebbe il significato di *congelare per il freddo* sicché nel brano che hai mostrato potrebbe avere il significato di *rimanere immobile per la paura* (invece che per il freddo).

Comment: Si "congelavano" quindi, nel senso che per la paura si rifiutavano di rispondere ai comandi e portarlo via.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: Seguendo il tuo indizio, sono riuscita a trovare qualcosa su [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=HT4rAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA46). A quanto pare, la citazione è dal libro *Sud e magia* di [Ernesto De Martino](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernesto_de_Martino).

Comment: @Charo A quanto pare sembra l'interpretazione più probabile: infatti da mio padre ho appreso che nel dialetto del mio paese (Maratea) tale verbo assume la forma di *attrassare* ed ha giustappunto il significato di *rimanere impietrito o congelato dalla paura*.

Comment: Ottimo, @AntonioMariaDiMauro! Vorresti scrivere una risposta? Sentiti libero di citare quel libro, se vuoi. Ho potuto controllare che la citazione è tratta da [*Sud e magia*](https://books.google.es/books/about/Sud_e_magia.html?id=BvCuKxPE0jQC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) di Ernesto De Martino.

Comment: @Charo Purtroppo non so dirti più di quello che già ti ho detto: consultando il mio vocabolario di greco ho cercato di capire se tale verbo possa discendere dalla lingua greca, ma sfortunatamente per ora non ho trovato alcunché. Ad ogni modo posso garantirti che semmai troverò qualcosa scriverò certamente una risposta.

Answer (score 2):

Ho chiesto ai miei genitori in quanto mi pareva di averglielo sentito usare nel loro dialetto (casertano) e da loro viene usato nel senso di pigrizia.
Per estensione si potrebbe pensare che le gambe di Rocchino, dalla paura, divennero pigre.
Cercando in tal senso ho trovato in questo [*Vocabolario napoletano*](https://books.google.it/books?id=HRK5Tw5COm0C&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=attassare%20napoletano&source=bl&ots=yH8hSycf2L&sig=ACfU3U3WUro1Ooe32axDS4905XaOSGgHIg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif2ujK99boAhVj_CoKHdE8CQAQ6AEwAXoECAwQLA#v=onepage&q=attassare%20napoletano&f=false) dell'Ottocento:

> ATTASSARE (v. n. e n. p. ). Istupidire, ma più nel senso fisico che morale. [...] essersi adoperata una tal voce prima in significato di arrestarsi, poi di far gelare il sangue ed arrestarne quasi la circolazione.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta! Mi sono permessa la libertà di aggiungere qualcosa dalla fonte che hai linkato.

Comment: Anche su [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=HT4rAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA46) si trova un'interessante citazione dal libro [*Sud e magia*](https://books.google.es/books/about/Sud_e_magia.html?id=BvCuKxPE0jQC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) di [Ernesto De Martino](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernesto_de_Martino). Mi sembra rilevante perché fa riferimento al significato di "attassamento" e "persona attassata" nei villaggi lucani, quindi nell'area geografica in cui si svolgono i fatti narrati nel romanzo. Sentiti libero/a di usare questa fonte, se vuoi.