# Cosa vuol dire "peduno"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Solo il capo dei dannati rimase serio. Stette in silenzio qualche istante, poi disse che il paese dell'eterno dolore era lí dov'erano nati, e dove i loro figli morivano di fame prima di crescere, dove si spezzavano i reni a lavorare la terra per gli estranei, e venivano offesi. Fai bene, disse, a prenderci per morti, perché oggi ci riempiamo la panza, ma domani queste quattro ossa che abbiamo se le piglia Tata Vittorio, le divide un pezzo **peduno**, e se ne fanno bottoni.

Questo "capo dei dannati" di cui parla il testo è in realtà il brigante [Carmine Donatelli, detto Crocco](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmine_Crocco).

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "peduno"? Non ho trovato questa parola su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Immagino si tratti di un termine di uso regionale.

Comment: Giusto un'idea... hai mai incontrato errori di stampa nei libri? Io sì, diverse volte.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Sì, certo! Ma, scusa, cosa c'entra questo con la domanda?

Comment: Niente. Assolutamente niente.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Se si arriva alla conclusione che si tratta di un errore di stampa, si chiude la domanda e basta. È accaduto qualche volta. Ma non dovrebbe essere un problema porre la domanda.

Comment: Ma chi ha detto che è un problema? Sei sempre sulla difensiva?

Comment: No, scusa, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: hai ragione: nessuno ha detto che sia un problema. È che non riesco a capire bene cosa vuoi dire con i tuoi commenti precedenti.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Potresti chiarire meglio che cosa intendi?

Comment: Suppongo che @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica voglia suggerire che sembri un refuso e che il testo corretto debba essere “un pezzo per uno”. È possibile, ma è anche possibile che sia una forma dialettale o idiolettica dell'autrice etc.

Comment: Ah! Capisco, @DaG! Infatti, ricercando "peduno" su Google si trova questa parola in qualche testo (in napoletano, credo), ma non sono riuscita a trovarne  il significato.

Comment: @DaG: E cosa sarebbe "un pezzo per uno" in questo contesto? Che tagliano le ossa a pezzi e poi distribuiscono un pezzo a ciascuno?

Comment: Ho trovato "peduno" in questo dizionario di dialetto napoletano http://www.vesuvioweb.com/it/wp-content/uploads/Giuseppe-Giacco-Vocabolario-napoletano-vesuvioweb.pdf e significa appunto "per ciascuno"

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Potresti scriverlo come risposta, per favore?

Comment: @DaG: Sembra trattarsi di parole dette dal personaggio storico  (non esattamente in questo modo, però).

Comment: @Charo È una italianizzazione di un espressione dialettale: nel mio paese assume la forma *appeduno* o *apperuno* ed è ha il significato di *a ciascuno*. Ad ogni modo in italiano è certo preferibile utilizzare il pronome *cadauno*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ho trovato il termine "peduno" in questo [dizionario di dialetto napoletano](http://www.vesuvioweb.com/it/wp-content/uploads/Giuseppe-Giacco-Vocabolario-napoletano-vesuvioweb.pdf) e rimanda alla voce "peruno" la quale significa appunto "per ciascuno".

Dovendo interpretare il senso esatto della frase, senza conoscere il libro, mi viene da pensare che questo Tata Vittorio sia una persona che "domina" su questi miserabili "dannati" con terribile ferocia, ed è capace di tritarli ad uno ad uno per fare bottoni delle loro ossa, un'immagine piuttosto forte per indicare il fatto che ha su di loro in pratica diritto di vita e di morte.

Comment: Potrebbe trattarsi di Vittorio Emanuele II?

Comment: @Charo dici? non ci avevo nemmeno pensato :) Questo da un senso leggermente diverso alla mia interpretazione... significherebbe quindi il completo disinteresse del Re per le miserie di queste persone, considerate solo come - per usare un'espressione assai nota - "carne da cannone".

Comment: Infatti, ricercando "Tata Vittorio" su Google ho trovato  [questo](https://books.google.es/books?id=r4WRAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT100&lpg=PT100&dq=%22Tata+Vittorio%22&source=bl&ots=DLGuojRReR&sig=ACfU3U2rvtR7F5bvDN9Tq9cYQorzNNsMdA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiu9M6TmNzoAhWOmBQKHY5UALcQ6AEwB3oECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Tata%20Vittorio%22&f=false).

Comment: Scusa di non averlo lasciato chiaro: il testo parla di "dannati" perché sta cercando di descrivere quello che pensa di loro [questo personaggio](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/12698/), Rocchino. Ma, in realtà, si tratta di briganti, perseguitati dal governo. E, infatti, Carmine Crocco Donatelli fu condannato a morte da Vittorio Emanuele II (di tutto questo non se ne parla nel libro, però). Appare anche [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=saIzCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT8&lpg=PT8&dq=%22Tata+Vittorio%22+Crocco&source=bl&ots=ttbIRbTQSk&sig=ACfU3U3sr3ZWxIKuyuTFRJoSLd7oB0f4KQ&hl=it&sa=X).